# PHP Explode and Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a string like:

```
clid=7 cid=55164 client_database_id=90507 client_nickname=Leandro client_type=0|clid=9 cid=55164 client_database_id=90507 client_nickname=Leandro1 client_type=0|clid=10 cid=55164 client_database_id=90507 client_nickname=Leandro2 client_type=0
```

The '|' is separator of clients.
I need to make an array like:

```
echo Client[0]['clid']; //return 7
echo Client[1]['clid']; //return 9
```

I'm trying do:

```
$clientList = explode('|', $clientList);
foreach($clientList as $client) {
    $aux[] = explode(' ', $client);
}
```

This code will result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => clid=7 [1] => cid=55164 [2] => client_database_id=90507 [3] => client_nickname=Leandro [4] => client_type=0 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => clid=9 [1] => cid=55164 [2] => client_database_id=90507 [3] => client_nickname=Leandro1 [4] => client_type=0 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => clid=10 [1] => cid=55164 [2] => client_database_id=90507 [3] => client_nickname=Leandro2 [4] => client_type=0 ) )
```

And it make a Array of Clients, but now i need explode in '=' but i cant

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't"?

Comment: I have no expertise to do :/

Comment: use preg_match to extract the result from array

Answer (score 3):

> but i cant

:) you can! :

```
$result = array();
foreach(explode('|', $str) as $record) {
    $r = array();
    foreach(explode(' ', $record) as $field) {
        $assignment = explode('=', $field);
        $r[$assignment[0]] = $assignment[1];
    }   
    $result []= $r; 
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(5) {
    'clid' =>
    string(1) "7"
    'cid' =>
    string(5) "55164"
    'client_database_id' =>
    string(5) "90507"
    'client_nickname' =>
    string(7) "Leandro"
    'client_type' =>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(5) {
    'clid' =>
    string(1) "9"
    'cid' =>
    string(5) "55164"
    'client_database_id' =>
    string(5) "90507"
    'client_nickname' =>
    string(8) "Leandro1"
    'client_type' =>
    string(1) "0"
  }

  ...
```

Comment: yup thats much faster than preg_match +1

Comment: @Leandro It's just another explode.. Your code was already *good* but not complete

Answer (score 0):

use regex to do it... simple and easy:

```
$string = "clid=7 cid=55164 client_database_id=90507 client_nickname=Leandro client_type=0|clid=9 cid=55164 client_database_id=90507 client_nickname=Leandro1 client_type=0|clid=10 cid=55164 client_database_id=90507 client_nickname=Leandro2 client_type=0";
if(preg_match_all("/(clid=[0-9]*)\s*(cid=[0-9]*)\s*(client_database_id=[0-9]*)\s*(client_nickname=\w+)\s*(client_type=[0-9]*)/i", $string, $matches))
{
   print_r($matches);

   //loop through records
   /*foreach($matches as $match)
   {

   }*/
}
```

not tested though

Comment: Simple and easy `/(clid=[0-9]*)\s*(cid=[0-9]*)\s*(client_database_id=[0-9]*)\s*(client_nickname=\w+)\s*(client_type=[0-9]*)/i` LOL :D

Comment: @hek2mgl - its a cleaner solution to use regex. I hate using explodes and 194 foreach loops. if the string changes all you need is to optimize the pattern and that's it. you don't have to go through the loops again. I can simplify it more if I want though..

Comment: Beside from the problem, that this gives not the expected output (it is far from), believe me, this is **not** a task for a regex.

Comment: yes it is.. if his string has one more space your solution will be worthless.. with regex you can validate your output and make sure its what you are looking for..

Comment: I said I didn't test it... I'm just giving him an idea how to do it without using worthless explodes and 10231 loops

Comment: I'm counting actually 3 loops. Give me a regex that produces the expected output if you can